# Setting the size of a tkinter frame inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to set the size of my VideoFrame, however, I can't seem to be able to access its size options. when using self.config I can access the background colour but the size does not change.

So I suspect it has something to do with the propagate option, but I don't know where, nor how to specify it as I am still getting used to object-oriented programing and this self notation is still a bit unclear for me.

So thanks for your help, I have attached the relevant part of the code, please note that VideoFrame is nested as follow: MainWindow>Display>VideoFrame

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.side = Display(self, SideVideoMenu)
        self.side.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.main_box = Display(self, VideoFrame)
        self.main_box.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2)
        self.top_menu = TopMenu(self)
        self.top_menu.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=tk.W)


# Display template with the option to change frame
class Display(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, start_class):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) # The master is the window in which the object (of class display) will be packed
        self.frame = None
        self.Switch_frame(start_class)

    def Switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_page = frame_class(self)
        if self.frame:
            self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = new_page
        self.frame.pack()


# Frame option for MainDisplay that shows the video preview
class VideoFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(width=500, height=500, bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text='video place holder', bg='#313335', fg='white').pack()
```

Comment: Yes, the propagate option can disable size propagation. But it's hard to find a problem in a code that does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to call `self.pack_propagate(0)`, otherwise `tk.Label(...).pack()` will shrink or expand the parent frame to fit its size.

Comment: It was as simple as that, thanks @acw1668